# A little help on creating a deck of cards

Tags: java

Just as a note, I can make a generic deck of cards no problem (with an enumerator for 52 separate cards), but I'm having trouble in a specific way of doing it which makes it more efficient.

The way I set up my code uses enumerators within enumerators. I have a Suit enumerator which simply contains the name of each suit, and a Card enumerator which contains the name, value, whether or not the card has been used, and the Suit of the Card.

The cards are put into a Deck constructor (which includes the name of the Deck and a Card array).

I'm using this card deck generator in my final project for my Grade 12 Computer Sciences class, and before deciding to post on here I asked my teacher to see if there was anything wrong with it. He told me that it would probably be something with the fact that I'm using enumerators, because my algorithm for generating the deck of cards isn't the problem.

**enum Suit:**

```
public enum Suit {
    // The suits
    HEARTS("Hearts"),
    DIAMONDS("Diamonds"),
    SPADES("Spades"),
    CLUBS("Clubs");

    // The properties of a suit
    private String name;

    /**
     * The constructor for creating a suit
     * @param name the name of the suit
     */
    private Suit(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the name of the suit
     * @return 
     */
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
}
```

**enum Card:**

```
public enum Card {
    // The cards
    ACE_LOW("Ace", 1),
    TWO("Two", 2),
    THREE("Three", 3),
    FOUR("Four", 4),
    FIVE("Five", 5),
    SIX("Six", 6),
    SEVEN("Seven", 7),
    EIGHT("Eight", 8),
    NINE("Nine", 9),
    TEN("Ten", 10),
    JACK("Jack", 11),
    QUEEN("Queen", 12),
    KING("King", 13),
    ACE_HIGH("Ace", 14);

    // The card properties
    private String name;
    private int value;
    private boolean isUsed;
    private Suit suit;

    /**
     * The constructor for making a Card
     * @param name the name of the card
     * @param value the value of the card
     */
    private Card(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.isUsed = false;
        this.suit = null;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the name of the card
     * @return the name of the card
     */
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    /**
     * Gets the value of the card
     * @return the value of the card
     */
    public int getValue() { return this.value; }
    /**
     * Gets whether or not the card has been used
     * @return returns true if the card has been used or false
     * if the card has not
     */
    public boolean isUsed() { return this.isUsed;}
    /**
     * Sets the suit of the card
     * @param suit the suit to set the card
     */
    public void setSuit(Suit suit) { this.suit = suit; }
    /**
     * Gets the suit of the card
     * @return returns the name of the suit
     */
    public String getSuit() { return this.suit.getName(); }
}
```

**class Constants:**

```
public class Constants {
    // Card sets
    public static Card[] cardSetAceHigh = {Card.TWO, Card.THREE, Card.FOUR,
        Card.FIVE, Card.SIX, Card.SEVEN, Card.EIGHT, Card.NINE, Card.TEN, Card.JACK,
        Card.QUEEN, Card.KING, Card.ACE_HIGH};
    public static Card[] cardSetAceLow = {Card.ACE_LOW, Card.TWO, Card.THREE,
        Card.FOUR, Card.FIVE, Card.SIX, Card.SEVEN, Card.EIGHT, Card.NINE, Card.TEN,
        Card.JACK, Card.QUEEN, Card.KING};

    // Suit set
    public static Suit[] suits = {Suit.HEARTS, Suit.DIAMONDS, Suit.SPADES, Suit.CLUBS};
}
```

**class Deck:**

```
public class Deck {
    // The deck properties
    Card[] cards;
    private String name;

    /**
     * The constructor for a deck, specifying the name
     * @param name the name of the deck
     */
    public Deck(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cards = null;
    }
    /**
     * The constructor for a deck, specifying all parameters
     * @param name the name of the deck
     * @param cards the cards in the deck
     */
    public Deck(String name, Card[] cards) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cards = cards;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the length of the deck
     * @return the length of the deck
     */
    public int getDeckLength() { return this.cards.length; }
    /**
     * Gets the name of the deck
     * @return the name of the deck
     */
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    /**
     * Makes a standard 52-card deck
     * @param aceHigh whether or not the ace's value is 1 or 14
     * @return the deck
     */
    public static Deck makeStandardDeck(boolean aceHigh) {
        int cardSetLength;
        Card[] set;
        if (aceHigh) {
            cardSetLength = Constants.cardSetAceHigh.length;
            set = Constants.cardSetAceHigh;
        }
        else {
            cardSetLength = Constants.cardSetAceLow.length;
            set = Constants.cardSetAceLow;
        }
        Card[] cards = new Card[Constants.suits.length * cardSetLength];
        for (int suit = 0; suit < Constants.suits.length; suit++) {
            for (int card = 0; card < cardSetLength; card++) {
                cards[(suit * cardSetLength) + card] = set[card];
                cards[(suit * cardSetLength) + card].setSuit(Constants.suits[suit]);
                Main.output(cards[(suit * cardSetLength) + card].getName() + "\t" + cards[(suit * cardSetLength) + card].getValue() + "\t" + cards[(suit * cardSetLength) + card].getSuit());
            }
        }
        Deck deck = new Deck("Standard deck", cards);
        return deck;
    }
    /**
     * Displays a deck and its contents
     * @param deck the deck to be displayed
     */
    public static void displayDeck(Deck deck) {
        String text = "Deck " + deck.getName() + " contents:\n";
        for (int card = 0; card < deck.getDeckLength(); card++) {
            text += deck.cards[card].getName() + "\t" + deck.cards[card].getValue() + "\t" + deck.cards[card].getSuit() + "\n";
        }
        Main.output(text);
    }
}
```

**class Main:**

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * The main method of the program
     * @param args 
     */
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Deck deck = Deck.makeStandardDeck(false);
        Deck.displayDeck(deck);
    }
    /**
     * Outputs a line of text
     * @param text the text to be outputted
     */
    public static void output (String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
}
```

When I run the program, I end up getting this as an output:

```
Ace 1   Hearts
Two 2   Hearts
Three   3   Hearts
Four    4   Hearts
Five    5   Hearts
Six 6   Hearts
Seven   7   Hearts
Eight   8   Hearts
Nine    9   Hearts
Ten 10  Hearts
Jack    11  Hearts
Queen   12  Hearts
King    13  Hearts
Ace 1   Diamonds
Two 2   Diamonds
Three   3   Diamonds
Four    4   Diamonds
Five    5   Diamonds
Six 6   Diamonds
Seven   7   Diamonds
Eight   8   Diamonds
Nine    9   Diamonds
Ten 10  Diamonds
Jack    11  Diamonds
Queen   12  Diamonds
King    13  Diamonds
Ace 1   Spades
Two 2   Spades
Three   3   Spades
Four    4   Spades
Five    5   Spades
Six 6   Spades
Seven   7   Spades
Eight   8   Spades
Nine    9   Spades
Ten 10  Spades
Jack    11  Spades
Queen   12  Spades
King    13  Spades
Ace 1   Clubs
Two 2   Clubs
Three   3   Clubs
Four    4   Clubs
Five    5   Clubs
Six 6   Clubs
Seven   7   Clubs
Eight   8   Clubs
Nine    9   Clubs
Ten 10  Clubs
Jack    11  Clubs
Queen   12  Clubs
King    13  Clubs
Deck Standard deck contents:
Ace 1   Clubs
Two 2   Clubs
Three   3   Clubs
Four    4   Clubs
Five    5   Clubs
Six 6   Clubs
Seven   7   Clubs
Eight   8   Clubs
Nine    9   Clubs
Ten 10  Clubs
Jack    11  Clubs
Queen   12  Clubs
King    13  Clubs
Ace 1   Clubs
Two 2   Clubs
Three   3   Clubs
Four    4   Clubs
Five    5   Clubs
Six 6   Clubs
Seven   7   Clubs
Eight   8   Clubs
Nine    9   Clubs
Ten 10  Clubs
Jack    11  Clubs
Queen   12  Clubs
King    13  Clubs
Ace 1   Clubs
Two 2   Clubs
Three   3   Clubs
Four    4   Clubs
Five    5   Clubs
Six 6   Clubs
Seven   7   Clubs
Eight   8   Clubs
Nine    9   Clubs
Ten 10  Clubs
Jack    11  Clubs
Queen   12  Clubs
King    13  Clubs
Ace 1   Clubs
Two 2   Clubs
Three   3   Clubs
Four    4   Clubs
Five    5   Clubs
Six 6   Clubs
Seven   7   Clubs
Eight   8   Clubs
Nine    9   Clubs
Ten 10  Clubs
Jack    11  Clubs
Queen   12  Clubs
King    13  Clubs
```

The problem is that when the deck is created, the suit for every card in the array turns into the last suit in the Constants.suits array (I tested this by changing around the order of the suits in the Constants.suits array).

Now from what I can tell, it's probably in the line:

```
Deck deck = new Deck("Standard deck", cards);
```

Because that's the only place where things can go wrong, since the suits are correct when filling in the Card array, but they magically change when being created into a Deck.

I really would like either a solution (if there is one) or an explanation (if there isn't one).

Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: One comment: An ACE is an ACE, there are not two different cards called ACE_HIGH and ACE_LOW.  Whether or not an ace is high or low depends on the context in which the deck is used. You should not mix the identity of the card with its interpretation in a particular context.  That should be handled in the context of the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enum` values are constant meaning you can only ever have one instance of them. So when you have a `Card.TWO` for example and you change it's suit to `Suit.SPADES`, then whenever you use `Card.TWO` anywhere it will have the suit `Suit.SPADES`. This is the problem you are running into. To solve this problem you will need to make the cards that go into your deck instances of a class and not values of an enum. Perhaps you can keep your `Card` (perhaps rename it to `CardName`) enum and have a class that represents a card in a deck that has a specific name (e.g. `CardName.TWO`) and suit (e.g. `Suit.SPADES`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes your professor is correct you either define all 52 cards in your `enum Card` specifying suite for each card or you create a `class Card`. The reason for that the last call to `setSuit(Suite suite)` will set suite for all `Card enum`

you can read more on [enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using an enum as a class to contain values as if they were seperate instances. In java there will be only one instance of an enum at any given time. For this reason you many times will not see setter methods in enum types.

So in your code:

```
cards[(suit * cardSetLength) + card] = set[card];
cards[(suit * cardSetLength) + card].setSuit(Constants.suits[suit]);
```

what is happening here is you set your cards[...] to the enum instance. Then you change the suit of that card, this changes the suit for every other card in your deck.

What you would want to do? Because this is homework I wont go into to great of detail but it looks like your almost there. Remove your setter methods in the `Card` class and maybe call it `CardValue` or something